# Stood up Domain Controller using a seperate domains DNS server. How do I create the dc/pdc/gc records in DNS?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dns-zone

So we have a non-standard setup that appears to be supported by Microsoft. Pretty much a Domain controller not hosting DNS (Using another Domains DNS server).

Delving into creating all of the records required and so far I have created the forward zone and various records I need.

When attempting to join Windows clients to this new domain, they fail stating the following record is missing:

```
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.one
```

So far I have only been able to create a _ldap._tcp._msdcs.domain.one record. I am unable to find a way to create the dc, domains, gc, or pdc folders that host the srv records in them giving me the full path required.

Any thoughts on how to get these sub folders created so my lookups work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution just testing different things in the lab. Needed to create a "New Domain" inside of _msdcs.domain.one called "dc", "pdc", and "gc" then add the SRV records for TCP/LDAP into those folders pointing to the new domains hostname.

Full details below to get this working for anyone that does a weird setup like this in the future.

- Create new AD server but do not select the DNS option to install.
- Once deployed/installed login to the server hosting your DNS server and create a forward lookup zone for your new domain.
- Create an (A) record and point it to your new domain controller
- Create a new forward lookup zone called "_msdcs.domain.name"
- Inside that zone, right click and create "New Domain"
- Add "dc", "pdc", and "gc" domains.
- Navigate into the dc folder and create a new SRV record for ldap/tcp and use the hostname of your new domain server.
- Create a new SRV record for kerberos/tcp and use the hostname of your new domain server.
- Create SRV records for ldap/tcp in the PDC folder as well using the hostname of your new domain server

From here your windows clients should be able to join the domain while pointing to this DNS server (you may need to update your TCP/IP settings and add your DNS suffix by selecting "Append these DNS suffices" and adding your domain info.